# Neo4j Auto Upgrade option

Tags: java, neo4j

Can you help me with a problem.

I have installed Neo4j version 2.0.0. And I've started the server. I'm trying to connect to it via a Java client(Java code in Eclipse).
Despite setting the property allow_store_upgrade=true in Neo4j.properties, I still get the 
exception.

> org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException:
>   Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable
>   automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter
>   "allow_store_upgrade=true"

Can any one help me. Please, I am stuck at this problem.

```
service = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(Neo4jDBPath);
```

It fails at this step. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer to your properties file. AFAIK, it isn't picked up automagically from your classpath.

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory()
    .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(storeDir)
    .loadPropertiesFromFile(pathToConfig + "neo4j.properties")
    .newGraphDatabase();
```

You could also configure it in java as follows:

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory()
    .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(storeDir)
    .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.allow_store_upgrade, "true")
    .newGraphDatabase();
```

For more information, see section "Starting an embedded database with configuration settings" on the following [page](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html).

Comment: what might be stopping i from getting picked up from the .properties file

Comment: tahts is very much helpful. Thanks a lot.. :-)